# onblur() is not working while onclick() is working fine

Tags: javascript, html

I need to make the notification list appear on the click which is working fine. But onblur() is not working at all.
Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eX2zQ/

Code:

html:-

```
<div class="one" onclick="hidetwo();" onblur="remove_the_notification();">
    <div> 
        <ul class="dropdown" id="notification" >
            <li><a href="#">kjhlkjhkjhklhjklj</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">kjhlkjhkjhklhjklj</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">kjhlkjhkjhklhjklj</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">See_All</a></li>
        </ul>       
</div>
</div>
```

css:-

```
.one{
    overflow: visible; 
    width: 21px; 
    height: 21px; 
    background-color:black; 
}
```

js:-

```
var show=0;

    function hidetwo(){
    if (show==0){
    document.getElementById('notification').style.display="block";
    show=1;
    }
    else if (show==1){
    document.getElementById('notification').style.display="none";
    show=0;
    }
    }

function remove_the_notification(){
    alert('hide one');
    if (show==0){
    document.getElementById('notification').style.display="block";
    show=1;
    }
    else if (show==1){
    document.getElementById('notification').style.display="none";
    show=0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have `onLoad` selected in the JSFiddle options. That means that your functions are hoisted *after* everything on the page is loaded, and so their references aren't available at the time that the handlers are attached. Also, AFAIK, without `contenteditable` your can't 'blur' a `<div>` - this event is usually for form elements like inputs. Perhaps you meant `onmouseleave`?

```
<div class="one" onclick="hidetwo();" onmouseleave="remove_the_notification();">
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/eX2zQ/1/)

Comment: Found [something about](http://help.dottoro.com/ljewsllu.php) `onmouseleave`. "The onmouseleave event is only supported by Internet Explorer, for a cross-browser solution, use the onmouseout event. The only difference between the onmouseleave and onmouseout events is that the onmouseout event propagates up the document hierarchy, while the onmouseleave does not."

Comment: thanks a lot. onmouseleave is working perfectly. I didn't know this before.

Answer (score 1):

Use `onmouseout` for this. This will trigger when the mouse is going outside the div.

[W3Schools onmouseout](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseout.asp)

Answer (score 1):

`onBlur()` event will work with `input` element like `text,file` . it will not working on `div`,so please try `onmouseLeave(),onmouseout()`

```
<div class="one" onclick="hidetwo();" onmouseout="remove_the_notification();">
```

Answer (score 1):

To make `onblur` event worked on `DIV` element you need to add `tabindex` attribute for `DIV`. For example:

```
<div class="one" onclick="hidetwo();"
     tabindex="0" onblur="remove_the_notification();">
  ...
</div>
```

Comment: Interesting. Didn't know you could do that.

Comment: I suggest you use the onmouseout event like the other guys suggested.

Comment: @Blackunknown, No. After adding `tabindex` `div` element can receive and lose focus. http://jsfiddle.net/eX2zQ/4/

Comment: I have used onmouseleave here. But thanks to all you guys for your time.

Comment: @AndrewD. I know it can, I just dont think it is best practice to do so when there is an event that suits the situation better in my opinion. I should have elaborated my first comment some more. My bad.